# Отловить запуск модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

В на страничке есть у меня такая вот ссылка замаскированная под кнопку,

```
<a style="margin-bottom:5px;background:#54A851;font-weight: 500;" class="btn"  href="#openModal'.$action.$rownum.'">Оценить</a>
```

Которая открывает модальное окно, сделано через CSS

```
<div id="openModal'.$action.$rownum.'" class="modalDialog">
```

Как отловить через JS открытие этого модального окна?

Comment: что значит сделано через css? это у вас бутстрап? добавьте [mcve]

Comment: `Event#click`, `MutationObserver`, магия...

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример!

Answer (score 0):

1) добавить для надежности кнопкам, вызывающим модалки класс, которой и будем ловить, например

```
class="btn js-for-modal-open"
```

2)Написать обработчик события для клика по кнопкам с классом "js-for-modal-open"

```
$(".js-for-modal-open").click(function(){
   alert("Got it!");
})
```